# How does Auth::attempt check password in Laravel?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, hash, bcrypt

I'm using Laravel 5.4. I know that hashing is one way thing. as I remembered, I hashed passwords and saved them on database and when i wanted to check user password I would hash their entered password and checked it with hashed string on database.

in laravel I only need to write below code:

```
 $email = $request['email'];
 $pass = $request['password'];

 if(Auth::attempt(['email'=> $email , 'password' => $pass])){
       //return something
   }
```

There is no need to `bcrypt($request['password']);` .

eventhough every time I have to use `bcrypt` the hash string would be different.

How `Auth::attempt` Hash password with `bcrypt` for checking passwords.

---

I need an explanation that how `Auth::attempt` works while using `bcrypt`. I know how to implement the code and check passwords.

Comment: Using bcrypt is not checking exact string rather by format which can't be decrypt in challenge

Comment: Ex. If it gives same string we can guess others password

Comment: They already built in `Auth::attempt` function ! So just check with that function

Comment: What have you tried to gather information about this? Laravel is open source, so why not check the source code for more details?

Comment: answer has been found. I was just editing my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/hashing) uses [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) for hashing password. `bcrypt` will generate random salt each time we use it. thats the reason we get different hash while we provide same `string`.

**how we can compare two hashes?**

random salt will save beside:

```
[full hash] = [random-salt-part]+[hashed-string-with-random-salt]
```

so for comparing we should use saved random-salt-part instead of using random salt. this way we gonna have same hash.

**why use random salt?**
in short : to fight against the likelyhood of being cracked by a rainbow table.
for more detailed answer visit: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/66989/how-does-a-random-salt-work

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the built-in `LoginController` and `RegisterController` classes that are included with your Laravel application, they will automatically use `Bcrypt` for registration and authentication.

For more details you can refer this link : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/hashing

The hashing method used by Laravel generates a different hash each time (even for the same string).it doesn't hash both strings and compare them, instead it uses the unhashed string to compare with the hash.

The check method allows you to verify that a given plain-text string corresponds to a given hash. However, if you are using the LoginController included with Laravel, you will probably not need to use this directly, as this controller automatically calls this method:

```
if (Hash::check('plain-text', $hashedPassword)) {
    // The passwords match...
}
```

Comment: I know i can use bcrypt. and i know that they use bcrypt as well. i just want to know how they can check hashes string while outcome of every bcrypt function with same input would be different

Comment: it does not compare with hash string it compare with plain password to hash string something like this   if (Hash::check('plain-text', $hashedPassword)) {}

Comment: hope this will help you to understand. let me know if you have any questions!!

Comment: bcrypt output changes every time , How can Hash::Check hash plain-text to what bcrypt created?

Comment: yes hash::check compare plain text with hashed text and return true if both strings matches..you can check my updated answer

Comment: still can't figure it out. i think hashing is one-way operation. you can't unhash strings. also if you hash plain-text again you will get different hash which will useless for comparison. sha1 hashed output for the same input was always the same .

Comment: yes you can't unhash string ,but you can check plain text string with hashed string if you want to compare both string then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152314/discussion-between-mehul-kuriya-and-amh).